# Cloud Functions Error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value, as well as TypeError: Cannot read property 'First_Name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a simple cloud function that should  create a new document in the specific collection with a specific name when a new user is created. I've tried various ways of coding this and I think I've come up with what I believe to be the closest to a working code as I can get it alone. This is the code in question:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.emailUserRegistration = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {



admin.firestore().collection('UnauthenticatedUsers').doc(user.email).get()
.then(snapshot => {

  var userObject = {
    Email: user.email,
    First_Name: snapshot.data().First_Name, 
    Last_Name:snapshot.data().Last_Name,
    Password:snapshot.data().Password,
    Phone_Number:snapshot.data().Phone_Number,
    Address:snapshot.data().Address
};
  return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(user.uid).set(userObject);
})
.catch(error => {
    //Handle the error
    console.log('[YAX]',error)
})
```

});

And the problems that occur are the following:

1) The function that is returned is undefined and a Promise or value is expected. I don't understand why this is a problem seeing as the set method returns a Promise. According to various tutorials that I've watched, both from Firebase's official YouTube channel and other independent programmer YouTubers, if a function returns a Promise you can simply return the function.

2) TypeError: Cannot read property 'First_Name' of undefined. I have absolutely no idea why the code wouldn't be able to read the 'First_Name' when I actually get it suggested as a possible variable after snapshot.data(). in Visual Studio Code.

3) This wasn't mentioned in the title, but for some reason despite the above two errors, the function execution returns with a status: 'ok'.

I'm a beginner Android developer and using Cloud Functions was the advice and solution I got from Firebase's Customer Support, but upon asking them this particular question, they haven't replied to me yet. Bear in mind that I am an even greater beginner in Node.js (I've never done anything in it before this project) and, apart from wanting my code to work, I most definitely want to know what's happening here, or in simpler terms I want to understand what the code does what it does and why it doesn't do what my logic says it should.

Has anyone any need for more context, I'll be more than happy to provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer to your first question**

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.emailUserRegistration = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {


// return this function
return admin.firestore().collection('UnauthenticatedUsers').doc(user.email).get()
.then(snapshot => {

  var userObject = {
    Email: user.email,
    First_Name: snapshot.data().First_Name, 
    Last_Name:snapshot.data().Last_Name,
    Password:snapshot.data().Password,
    Phone_Number:snapshot.data().Phone_Number,
    Address:snapshot.data().Address
};
  return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(user.uid).set(userObject);
})
.catch(error => {
    //Handle the error
    console.log('[YAX]',error)
})
});
```

**The answer to your second question**
It is better if you upload a pic of your **UnauthenticatedUsers** document.

```
 First_Name: snapshot.data().First_Name // this should be same as in your document and it is case sensitive also please check with your document.
```

Hope this will help you......

Comment: Your answer would work, but due to firebase's back-end with storing users in their database and the whole authentication part of it, sometimes when you try to retrieve a user's info before they're authenticated, it'll return a null value. This is the official statement that I got from the firebase support team. In the future, one will be able to overcome this hardship when they develop an onValidate trigger for the user: currently we've only got onCreate and onDelete to work with. Thanks for answering :D